# What is the length of an signed transaction ? ( to be sent by method eth_sendRawTransaction )

Tags: transactions, signature, raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction

I have spent days on signing a raw transaction, but all are failed.

Now I want to know, what is the length of a raw transaction? and can you give me an real example of a signed transaction?

#### For example,

I want to do this quite simple transaction:

```
send 0.00xx ETH from address 1 to address 2, with no comment
```

my parameters are:

```
{
  nonce: '0x44e',
  gasPrice: '0x29e8d60800',
  gasLimit: '0x59d8',
  to: '0x3Ae7a18407B17037B2ECC4901c1b77Db98367cDA',
  value: '0x37b4e07e14000',
  data: '0x'
}
```

and the result of signing with private key is : （using a lib named  `@ethereumjs/tx`）

```
0xf86d82044e8529e8d608008259d8943ae7a18407b17037b2ecc4901c1b77db98367cda87037b4e07e140008025a096815bf332f590506df079b666cc198816d690a7d251fe8aa8c8c70c82752c7ba03afe5ffc239c9d4c4f36850f4413afc97eed68f70839559d466c3924ec340059
```

It's length is 224. is it correct ?

thanks a lot!

Comment: It can be any length, obviously.

Comment: what about sending ETH from address-1 to address-2, without any comment? (`data` filed is null )

Comment: Yup, that would have the same constant size regardless of the addresses or the amount of ETH.

Comment: I get the same length using web3.js.

Comment: After decoding the transaction [with](flightwallet.github.io/decode-eth-tx) in mainnet I see a gap in the nonces for the sender account: last mined nonce is 917 and the one used is 1102. So unless the in between nonces are mined the transaction will not be mined. If you run your own node they might be stuck in the pending queue with low gas price, or the account doesn't have enough ether to pay the transaction fee and sent value.

Comment: @Ismael thank you so much!  I found the root cause: `nonce` is not correct. so my previous attempts are failed.  after I assigned the correct `nonce` then signed, the tx broadcasted successfully.